# ImportError: cannot import name 'LayoutlmConfig' from 'layoutlm

Tags: python, machine-learning, pdf, nlp, ocr

I am trying to save the predictions for the LayoutLM model.

paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13318

Notebook - https://www.kaggle.com/code/iamarjunchandra/layoutlm-document-sequence-labeling-model/notebook

```
The problem arises when I run the below code for making prediction 
! python unilm/layoutlm/examples/seq_labeling/run_seq_labeling.py 
                               --do_predict 
                               --data_dir data 
                               --model_type layoutlm 
                               --model_name_or_path output 
                               --output_dir output 
                               --labels data/labels.txt \
                               --fp16
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unilm\\layoutlm\\examples\\seq_labeling\\run_seq_labeling.py", line 53, in <module>
    from layoutlm import FunsdDataset, LayoutlmConfig, LayoutlmForTokenClassification
ImportError: cannot import name 'LayoutlmConfig' from 'layoutlm' (c:\Users\jyoti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\layoutlm\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Hi, which version of layoutlm are you using? Also, where can I find that python script (unilm/layoutlm/examples/seq_labeling/run_seq_labeling.py) ? In master branch in github it seems deprecated(https://github.com/microsoft/unilm/tree/master/layoutlm). Thats why I'm asking

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for looking into the problem.
I am using the layoutlmV1 model. I am using the very first version of the layoutLM model. Please find the link for the code - https://github.com/jyotiyadav94/layoulmModel